# How to 'resume' game on SKScene1 after transitioning to SKScene2?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, transition

Perhaps I'm not using the correct keywords to search but I haven't had any luck in finding out how to do this. I am developing a game for the AppStore using Xcode's sprite kit. I have the main game play on `SKScenePlay.m` and when we click a pause button (an `SKSpriteNode`) on `SKScenePlay`, I transition to `SKScenePause` with the following code:

```
SKScene *PauseScene = [[SKScenePause alloc] initWithSize:self.size];
[self.view presentScene:PauseScene];
```

I have a resume button on the `SKScenePause` that does the following to transition back to `SKScenePlay`:

```
SKScene *PlayScene = [[SKScenePlay alloc] initWithSize:self.size];
SKTransition *reveal = [SKTransition flipHorizontalWithDuration:0.5];
[self.view presentScene: PlayScene transition:reveal];
```

but when I go back to `SKScenePlay`, the game is reset (score, player position, et cetera). How would I, after pausing the game to go from `SKScenePlay` to `SKScenePause`, transition from `SKScenePause` to back to `SKScenePlay` while saving the state of everything in `SKScenePlay`?

P.S: To actually pause the game, all of the `SKSpriteNode`'s (which are the objects in my game that move and fall around) are children of an `SKNode` *background, and I set background.paused=true and this pauses all the `SKActions` in `SKScenePlay`.

Answer (score 1):

Using your current code, you can't. At least not in any short and simple way. Your code trashes the PlayScene and transitions to PauseScene.

Your choices are to:

1) Include pause code in your PlayScene to handle whatever it is you need done without transitioning to a new scene.

2) Save all your relevant data in your PlayScene before transitioning to PauseScene and loading the saved data when transitioning back to PlayScene.

There's really no reason to have a new scene for a pause menu, so I would recommend you work to incorporate your pause code into your PlayScene.

Answer (score 0):

1)You need to add children view controller in the container view controller in a stack. So You just put the view of new view controller above first one.

2)when you press "play" or "resume" button you just remove top view controller from the stack and game resumes.

I have made absolutely the same but on swift.
hope it helps.